# MySQL Multiple Left Join Limit

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

How would I impose a left join limit on query with multiple left joins that depend on one another? See comment below on the LIMIT:

```
SELECT 
    a.*,GROUP_CONCAT(c.body SEPARATOR ' ') AS bodies
FROM a   
    LEFT JOIN b ON b.id_a=a.id    
    LEFT JOIN c ON c.id=b.id_c LIMIT 5 # LIMIT 5 Here Does Not Work 
WHERE ...
```

Sample data set...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `a`;
CREATE TABLE `a` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
);

-- Contains relationship between a and c
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `b`;
CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `id_a` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_c` int(11) NOT NULL
);

-- Contains body contents
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `c`;
CREATE TABLE `c` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `body` varchar(2000) NOT NULL
);


-- ----------------------------
-- Sample Records
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('1');

INSERT INTO `b` VALUES 
('1','1'), ('1','2'), ('1','3'),
('1','4'), ('1','5'), ('1','6'),
('1','7'), ('1','8'), ('1','9'), 
('1','10');

INSERT INTO `c` VALUES
('1','aa'),('2','bb'), ('3','cc'),
('4','dd'), ('5','ee'), ('6','ff'),
('7','gg'), ('8','hh'), ('9','ii'),
('10','jj');
```

... and SQLFiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1822/12

Also here is a subquery rewrite that I tried but doesn't work because the outer table is not accessible from the nested subquery and fails with "unknown column a.id in where clause": http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1822/3

Also here is a subquery find_in_set rewrite http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d43bb/1 which works but is too slow with large data sets.

Comment: what is not working ?

Comment: Can't seem to enforce a LIMIT of 5 on the left join. See the last line of the query for the issue

Comment: What is `LIMIT 5` supposed to mean in this context? At most 5 random matching rows?

Comment: Yes, 5 matching left join rows

Comment: aaah I got it now, you want the LIMIT on the jointure and not the final results... it doesnt work like that

Comment: Yeah sorry I edited it to make it clearer. See the SQLFiddle for a working example

Comment: Perhaps a [common table expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-syntax) could work. Somewhat like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1822/27).

Comment: common table expressions could work but unfortunately I'm not able to upgrade to MySQL 8 which just went GA recently

Answer (score 2):

You can use variables to number each row in the subquery.  Then you can filter out rows based on that number.  This example limits the `left join` to at most 3 results with the same `t1_id`:

```
select  *
from    table1 t1
left join
        (
        select  @rn := case when t1_id = @prev_id then @rn + 1 else 1 end rn
        ,       @prev_id := t1_id
        ,       t2.*
        from    table2 t2
        order by
                t1_id
        ) t2rn
on      t2rn.t1_id = t1.id
        and t2rn.rn < 4  -- At most 3 rows
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b012/2/0)

Comment: elegant solution

Comment: How can I make this work with multiple left joins though? For example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1822/12

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proper way to write this using variables.  Andomar's solution might work, but it suffers three issues:

- In more recent versions of MySQL, the `order by` needs to be in a subquery.
- More importantly, MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `select`.  So, you should not assign a variable in one expression and use it in another.
- The variables are not initialized in the query

So, a better version looks like:

```
select . . .
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.*,
             (@rn := if(@id = t2.t1_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@id := t2.t1_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select t2.*
            table2 t2
            order by t1_id
           ) t2 cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @id := -1) params
     ) t2
     on t2.t1_id = t1.id
where t2.rn <= 5;  -- At most 5 rows
```

Your use of `group_concat()` suggests that a `group by` is also necessary.  However, your question seems more general about limiting the rows and you don't provide much information on what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: No need to initialize variables if you're okay with a `null` initial value?

Comment: @Andomar . . . Assuming they haven't already been initialized during the session.  That is a particular risk when running the query multiple times during debugging.

Comment: I don't think order by t1_id does anything useful - and there's an an uncharacteristic error at the bottom of this query

Comment: @Strawberry: the `order by t1_id` is required for the `if` constructs to work correctly

Comment: @andomar Nope. The order by is in the wrong place for that.

Comment: @Strawberry: Did you read the first bullet point in the answer?

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Once upon a time, `group by`s needed to be a subquery for variables to work.  Then, some new version came out (maybe 5.6.x ?) and `order by`s joined the `group by`s.  Then was decreed a newer version and a miracle occurred:  variables are no longer needed in 8.0 for this calculation.  But that's another matter.